# Alpha and Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

(The type I error, alpha) Which one of the statements about the alpha level is correct?
a) The alpha level is the predefined probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is false. 
b) The alpha level is the estimated probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is false. 
c) The alpha level is the estimated probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis true. 
d) The alpha level is the predefined probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: This is the type of question (like a test question or homework problem). It requires the self study tag. All you can expect are hints which is difficult to provide when the question has multiple choice answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha Level is the probability of falsely "rejecting" the null-hypothesis (assuming it's true), meaning you should have "failed to reject" the null-hypothesis. We're forbidden by Frequentist Theory of "Accepting the null-hypothesis". We can only "reject" or "fail to reject" the null-hypothesis. When performing hypothesis tests and calculating p-values, we do that under the guise that the Null-Hypothesis is true. Then reject if p-value < alpha, and fail to reject if p-value > alpha.

In relation to your answers.....I would go with D, since it is a predefined probability before analysis (perhaps even the study) begins and we assume the null-hypothesis is true.